# php пропустить первый Array Foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Доброго времени суток, ребят нужна помощ.
Есть код

```
foreach ($Reader as $Row)
    {    

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($Row);
        echo '<pre>'; 

    }
```

Выводит :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3 
...

)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3 
...

)
...
```

нужно удалить первый Array и что бы продолжило перебирать дальше!

Comment: Думайте логически.  Есть цикл, итерации можно считать. Первую надо пропустить. Далее решение очевидное напрашивается. Или подскажите, что именно вам не понятно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить триггер.

```html
$isFirst = true;

foreach ($Reader as $Row)
{    
  if ($isFirst)
  {
    $isFirst = false;
    continue;
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($Row);
  echo '<pre>'; 
}
```

Или изменить представление

```html
foreach ($Reader as $key => $value)
{    
  if ($key == 0)
    continue;

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($value);
  echo '<pre>'; 
}
```

Comment: для второго варианта больше случаев будет, когда это не работает, чем работает.

Comment: Возможно. Писал на коленке.

Comment: Спасибо , первый заработал !

Comment: я про то, что второй код будет работать, если `$reader` это обычный индексированный массив а-ля `[1,2,3]`. В случае, когда это ассоциативный массив, или итератор, или еще что-то, работать оно не будет.  А судя по названию переменной `$reader` это вряд ли вообще массив.

Comment: @teran, ваша правда.